# How to output the second value in the string between the two delimiters using regex?

Tags: php, regex

I am fetching data from a text file. How can I fetch the value in between the two delimiters i.e. | based on the match. The first 7 characters are part of the id.

Input Example:

```
    0123456|BHKAHHHHkk|12345678|JuiKKK121255
    9100450|HHkk|12348888|JuiKKK10000000021sdadad255
```

Desired Output:
`BHKAHHHHkk` based on the `searchfor` value = `0123456`

My Script:

```
$file = 'file.txt';


// the following line prevents the browser from parsing this as HTML.
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

// get the file contents, assuming the file to be readable (and exist)
$contents = file_get_contents($file);
// escape special characters in the query
$txt = explode("\n",$contents);

$counter = 0;
foreach($txt as $key => $line){
    $subbedString = substr($line,2,6);

   // $searchfor = '0123456';
    //echo strpos($subbedString,$searchfor); 
    if(strpos($subbedString,$searchfor) === 0){
        $matches[$key] = $searchfor;
        
          echo  "<p>" . $matches[$key] . "</p>";
          
                  $counter += 1;
                  if($counter==10) break;
         
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`preg_match` function can be used for this purpose and it makes your code very simple and readable.

Each row of data starts with `\n` or start of the content, so `\n|^` for the beginning of the pattern is used; Also `?:` is used to prevent listing this part in the `$matchs` variable.

Each row of data ends with `\n` or end of content, so `\n|$` for the end of the pattern is used; `\r` may appear or not so `(?:\r?\n|$)` used at the end.

`$searchfor` variable can be directly in the pattern.

`\|([^\n]+)` searchs for delimiters and rest of line data.

In the end, the second parameter of the data (which you looking for) can be accessed in the `$matchs[1]` variable and the rest of the data in the `$matchs[2]` variable.

```
<?php

$contents = '0123456|BHKAHHHHkk|12345678|JuiKKK121255
9100450|HHkk|12348888|JuiKKK10000000021sdadad255';

$searchfor = '9100450';

if(preg_match('/(?:\n|^)' . $searchfor .  '\|([^|]+)(.*?)(?:\r?\n|$)/is', $contents, $matchs))
{
    $second_value = $matchs[1];
    $reset_values = $matchs[2];
    echo "Result for searching <b>$searchfor</b> is <b>$second_value</b> and reset of data is <b>$reset_values</b>";
}
else echo('Not Found :(');

?>
```

Comment: perfect! also, how can I retrieve the third value in between the delimiters using your logic.  e.g. 12345678  . Thank you.

Comment: Thanks; The pattern can change to `'/(?:\n|^)' . $searchfor .  '\|([^|]+)\|([^|]+)\|([^|]+)(?:\r?\n|$)/is'` and values can read from `$matchs[1]`, `$matchs[2]` and `$matchs[3]`.

Comment: sorry for bugging you. How can I limit it to only echo the first found match? not all the matches. Thank you.

Comment: Also, how can I do a reverse lookup meaning search the 3rd value and return the id and second value? Thank you.

Comment: It's easy, try to learn it. Rules are here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp. 
for 2nd part: `'/(?:\n|^)([^|]+)\|' . $searchfor .  '\|([^|]+)\|([^|]+)(?:\r?\n|$)/is'`,
for 3rd part: `'/(?:\n|^)([^|]+)\|([^|]+)\|' . $searchfor .  '\|([^|]+)(?:\r?\n|$)/is'`,
for 4th part: `'/(?:\n|^)([^|]+)\|([^|]+)\|([^|]+)\|' . $searchfor .  '(?:\r?\n|$)/is'`

Comment: Also in this code, only the first matched value will print. If printing all matches is needed `preg_match_all` can use.

Comment: thank you so much, highly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Using regular expressions works for me:

```
$input = '0123456|BHKAHHHHkk|12345678|JuiKKK121255
9100450|HHkk|12348888|JuiKKK10000000021sdadad255';

$searchfor = '12348888';

$regexp = "/(?<=" . $searchfor . "\\|)\\w+/m";

$result = preg_match_all($regexp, $input, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Output:

```
/*Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => JuiKKK10000000021sdadad255
        )

)*/
```

Comment: how to fetch the 2nd value instead of the 4th value in between the delimiters using your logic

Comment: Set the $searchfor variable to the corresponding id: $searchfor = '0123456';